# Add data from two databases into one gridview

Tags: c#, linq, gridview

I have two different databases, and want to take data from both databases and insert it into a gridview.

Here is my problem:

DB1 has two tables from which I need to pull data

**User**   
 
FName
LName
Email
*UserId*
*UserName*

**UserData**
Role
Department
*UserId*

DB 2 has 1 table from which i need to pull data

**Login**
CreateDate
*UserName*

My gridview ultimately needs to display the following:

fName lName Email Department Role CreateDate

I somehow need to connect these three tables into 1 gridview. I do not have control over the database, so I cannot create any new tables. My problem is that I cannot seem to link these successfully. Any ideas on how to go about tackling this?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually bind your gridview using `DataBind()` to an in memory union of the three database tables. Look at the `LINQ` `Union()` extension method / operator.

Another approach would be to create a view over the three databases and bind to that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Entity Framework, you can form 2 queries to extract data from DB1 and DB2 and then join the two queries and finally via a new anonymous type select wanted columns. Notice that two queries need to be **IEnumerable (not IQueriable)** because they belong to two different contextes.

Answer (score 0):

```
from u in User
join ud in UserData on u.UserId equals ud.UserId
join l in Login on u.UserName equals l.UserName
select new { fName=u.FName, LName=u.LName, Email=u.Email, Dept=ud.Department, Role=ud.Role, CreateDate=l.CreateDate};
```

Comment: This results in the following error: The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [View](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28SQL%29) with a simple [Join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) use this as your `DataSource` for your `GridView`. Then either edit the columns on your `GridView` to display only the fields you are interested in, or make your `View` return only those columns. Your select could be something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS
SELECT u.fname,
       u.lname,
       u.email,
       ud.department,
       ud.role l.CreateDate
FROM db1.dbo.USER u
INNER JOIN db1.dbo.userdata ud ON u.userid = ud.userid
INNER JOIN db2.dbo.login l ON u.username = l.username
```

Then you can use it like:

```
SELECT * FROM myview
```

And more advanced queries:

```
SELECT * FROM myview WHERE userid=1
```

**Optional Reading**: [Create Linked Servers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx)

Comment: is there a way to do this with Linq?

Comment: Yes there are ways to do this with Linq. But it makes more sense to have this type of logic in the Database server (and faster).