# Load RSS feeds into GridView's DataSource

Tags: c#, xml, gridview, rss, datasource

On my Page_Load event

```
DataSet oDs = new DataSet();
oDs.ReadXml("http://stackoverflow.com/feeds");
gvFeeds.DataSource = oDs.Tables[2];
gvFeeds.DataBind();
```

This populates the GridView as shown below

[image]

The DataSet contains 8 DataTables: **Feed, Title, Link, Entry, Rank, Category, Author, Summary**

DataTable[2] for example, contains the 30 most recent post's **Links**, as shown above.

---

What I want is for the GridView to show each records **Feed, Title, Link, Entry, Rank, Category, Author, Summary**

But, when I assign the enter DataSet to the DataSource, it just populates the GridView as if I had assigned it the DataTable[0] object... being the parent feed's header information.

Answer (score 2):

You can only bind the GridView to one table.
For Example, Use the following will bind to "Link" table.

```
gvFeeds.DataSource = oDs;
gvFeeds.DataMember = "Link";
gvFeeds.DataBind();
```

However, if all of your tables share the same schema (which is less likely), then you can manually create a new DataTable by dumping rows and then bind it.

There is yet one more scenario described in this post
[Add data from two databases into one gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792418/add-data-from-two-databases-into-one-gridview)

Comment: This also just shows the record's "Link" information... not all 8 columns being Feed, Title, Link, Entry, Rank, etc...

Comment: Oh! My apologies. I thought you were trying to display just "Link".
However, I am not sure whether you will be able to achieve what you are trying to unless all of these tables have the same schema. If all of these tables do have same schema, then probably you might need to dump them into one temporary table before binding.

Comment: So is there a way to take the XML and make it form a single DataTable with the information I need?  How can I best make the desired end-result with the data available?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to combine data from various tables and bind it to a single gridView at a time.

Edit:

```
        //Considering you have all the tables that share the same schema
        //i.e. All are having same column names and types

        //Create an In Memory DataTable
        DataTable consolidateTable = new DataTable("ConsolidatedTable");

        //Add columns with that is same across all of you tables
        consolidateTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("firstColumn"));
        consolidateTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("secondColumn"));
        //etc..

        //Now go through each record of each table
        foreach (DataTable dt in oDs.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                consolidateTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }

        //bind
        gvFeeds.DataSource = consolidateTable;
        gvFeeds.DataBind();
```

Do consider that this is only possible if all the tables have same schema (i.e. same firstColumn, secondColumn, etc. Otherwise, this is not possible.

Comment: So is there a way to take the XML and make it form a single DataTable with the information I need?  How can I best make the desired end-result with the data available?